# Use of server and root certificate in ssl termination and inspection

Tags: encryption, tls, ids, cisco

I'm researching vendors which allow SSL termination and inspection, I came across Cisco CWSA technology, the technology was somewhat easy to understand the stuff which really boggled my mind was the difference between `root` and `server` certificate.

This [article](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/117792-technote-wsa-00.html) mentions:

> A Server certificate cannot be used in order to sign other
>   certificates; therefore, HTTPS decryption does not work if a Server
>   certificate is installed on the WSA.

I'm mean if that certificate is signed by root CA, then why it can't go there on appliance for decryption? I'm missing something here. Help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between the capabilities of a "root" certificate, which can be used to sign other certificates and a "server" certificate which cannot.

For an SSL proxy if you use a server certificate then the only host whose traffic could be seemlessly intercepted is the one whose Common Name is included on the server cert.

The general idea with this kind of SSL intercepting proxy is that you'll have a CA certificate which will be trusted by the clients connecting through the proxy and which can be used to create server certificates that the clients will trust, on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks @Rory for reply. So, tech speaking you can you use server certificate to decrypt.Why CISCO has then made it sound impossible?

Comment: well you can but it wouldn't be a lot of use as it'd only decrypt traffic for one server :) I don't know for sure why cisco would block this, but my guess would be that if the product is intended for use as a general SSL proxy, it will only serve that function effectively with a root cert deployed to it, so they're writing their documentation from that perspective..

Comment: You have a point but what about inbound ssl decryption instead of outbound where gmail, facebook, skype more of application control and policing required. In my case its just one server which needs to be inspected for layer 7  attacks?

Comment: well as I say, don't know the product, my guess was it would be intended for outbound rather than inbound, so that may be their reasoning. In my experience in-bound to a web app. for examples tends to be done by a different class of product (e.g. WAF), although it is similar work being done...